# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I am getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

this is my JavaScript Code:

```
    saveButton.addEventListener("click" function() {
    const textToSave = inputTextField.value;
    console.log("I am going to save " + textToSave + " to Firestore");
    docRef.set({
        quote: textToSave
    }).then(function() {
        console.log("Status saved!");
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Got an error: ", error);
    });
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I suppose is complaining about `saveButton.addEventListener("click" function()` missing a `,`. It should be `saveButton.addEventListener("click", function()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a comma after "click".

```
saveButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  ...
});
```